# Weird conversion from String to float

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, string

I have a webview with javascript-interface.

From within this webview i do certain javascript operations.

In one of those i set an onclick attribute for one of the elements in my webcontent. ( using jquery)

```
button.attr("onclick", "Android.doStuff(".concat(stringContainingOnlyNumbers).concat(")"));
```

As you might guess the variable stringContainingOnlyNumbers holds a String containing only numbers.

Android is the keyword for my javascript-interface.

If i click the button i manipulated the method doStuff is gettin called on the interface.

Everything fine so far.

But what the String Parameter holding looks like a float value.

So what looks like this on js side:

```
1344810353
```

Comes out on my interface like this:

```
1.34447e+09
```

Can anyone help me out here and explain why this conversion happens?

Comment: How are you putting it in your interface?  It's just using scientific notation to display the number.  Depending on how you output it, you might be able to tell it to not use scientific notation.

Comment: I use androids Log. Any idea how to prevent or revert that notation?

Comment: JS interface does some odd things. I noticed that a Java function returning a String is returning Javascript `object` type, not `string`. Adding ""+returnvalue fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't really a conversion, it's just rewriting it to fewer decimal digits using scientific notation.
1344810353 rounded to 6 digits is 1.34447e+09, which btw is 1.34447 * 10^9.
It's a float, and javascript tends to shorten numbers when concatenating them as strings.
Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YGC8B/
You can fix this by iterating through the numbers digits and displaying them one by one.

```
function getString(number) {
    var numstring = "";
    var num = number;
    while (num > 0) {
        numstring = num % 10 + numstring;
        num -= num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return numstring;
}
var number = 1344810353;
log(getString(number)); // or however your output it
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tj5Zy/

A side note:
It's best not to use the **onclick** attribute of an element, it's slightly deprecated. I would recommend attaching the event.
And since you're using jQuery, it's just all the easier.

```
button.bind('click',function() {
    Android.doStuff(stringContainingOnlyNumbers);
});
```

Comment: Thx, should do it! Gonna try when I'm back on it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening there is not a conversion to float, but you are getting a scientific notation for that integer. It must be happening in concat.
Can't you do something like:

```
button.attr("onclick", "Android.doStuff(" + stringContainingOnlyNumbers + ")");
```

?

Comment: Unfortunately this is what i tryed before. Ended in the same result.